# Try {} Catch {} Not working as it should in C#

Tags: c#, try-catch

I have a `try {} catch {}` for each line my user inputs something, this is to ensure it's in the right format/range/acceptable. However it doesn't seem to... well work! Here is one of my examples.

```
string userAnswer;
        bool errorHandling = true;
        while (errorHandling){

            try{
                userAnswer = Console.ReadLine();

                if (userAnswer == "1") {
                  singleGrade.grapher(acount, bcount, ccount, dcount, ecount, fcount);
                }else{
                    if (userAnswer == "2"){
                      readIn.Classes(SingleGrade[1]);

                    }else{
                        if (userAnswer == "3"){
                           countAll.allGrades(multiGrade);
                        } else{
                           errorHandling = false;
                        }
                     }
                  }
              }
        catch (FormatException a){
                Console.WriteLine(a.Message);
                //Console.WriteLine("Error - please enter a number between 1 & 6.");
            }
    } // end of While loop
```

If someone could please explain to me why no error is caught when an invalid number is placed/not in the correct format.

Comment: Some other exception is being thrown, or none is being thrown at all.  Change `FormatException` to `Exception`

Comment: Please post a *short* but complete program demonstrating the problem. We have no idea what `grapher` does, or what you expect to throw a `FormatException`. I strongly recommend that you start following .NET naming conventions though.

Comment: There is no exception thrown. If input is something else than 1, 2 or 3, it just ends up in the line 'errorhandling = false'

Comment: This also looks like a situation where you are trying to use exception handling for flow control. The user entering a number outside the range of 1-6 isn't an exceptional situation as you can easily check for it. The entire exception block could just be replaced by an if statement and have the same effect.

Comment: What I would like it to do is this:

Comment: User enters a number between 1 and 6 (there are 6 options - didn't want to paste them all). If it's any of the 6 options, it calls up the objects. If it's outside 1-6 or a different format, it throws an exception, tells the user that it's wrong, and then loops back to the start where they can enter another number.

Comment: @OliSmart Check my updated answer.  Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

There is no `FormatException` being thrown because valid strings are being entered.  If you were to convert the user input to an integer, for example, that would throw a `FormatException`.  But since you are leaving it as a string, no exception is being thrown.

However, since you are really only trying to restrict user input, and nothing truly exceptional is happening here, you should probably just handle it through you application logic.

What you are really looking for is probably  something like this:

```
bool errorHandling = true;
while (errorHandling)
{
        string userAnswer = Console.ReadLine();   
        switch (userAnswer)
        {
            case "1":
              singleGrade.grapher(acount, bcount, ccount, dcount, ecount, fcount);
              errorHandling = false;
              break;

            case "2":  
              readIn.Classes(SingleGrade[1]);
              errorHandling = false;
              break;

            case "3":
              countAll.allGrades(multiGrade);
              errorHandling = false;
              break;

            // cases for 4, 5, and 6...

            default:
              Console.WriteLine("Error - please enter a number between 1 & 6.");
              break;
        }        
} // end of While loop
```

Comment: OP stated that he was entering invalid strings

Comment: @RufusL Let me rephrase: "valid" as far as .NET Framework is concerned, not as far as his application logic is concerned.

Comment: Ok so changing the userAnswer to an integer would throw an exception if a string is placed? What then if it was outside the range required?

Comment: @OliSmart Correct.  If it is outside the range required, then it would fall into the `default` case in the `switch` statement (or the final `else` part of your orignal `if` block).  You would probably want to handle it there, either by throwing the exception yourself or by displaying an error message.

Comment: You need to check for that yourself. It is not an exceptional situation like a conversion error from the Convert.ToInt32. You would add additional cases for 4-6. Everything not 1-6 would be handled by the default case. Probably better to use int.TryParse() and remove the exception handling all together.

Comment: @BradD Good point.  This is really not a valid use of exceptions.

Comment: Ok thank you I shall try it. How come this has been downvoted so much as well by the way? How can I improve the way I ask my questions so I don't lose so many points?

Answer (score 0):

You're not throwing and exception when the number is invalid, you're just handling a bunch of `if` statements - thus, since there is no `throw` statement, nothing can hit the `catch` statement, and insteadyou're seeing what we colloquially call a "Fall through error" - logic is proceeding past where it should.

If you want an exception when input is invalid, just add a `throw new FormatException` to the end of the `if` statements, so you get a "if we make it here there's a problem" behaviour.

Comment: That probably isn't the correct exception type to throw in this scenario.  Either convert the string to another data type and let the framework throw the exception, or throw some custom exception type on your own.  But technically, as the code is currently written, there is no `FormatException` occurring.

Comment: Exception handling is anyway unnecessary in this scenario. Easier (and less costly) is just show an error message when input is something else than '1', '2' or '3'

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are grabbing a string, and not trying to convert it to anything else, so there is no `FormatException`.

I would get away from using the `try / catch` for input validation, and instead use the `TryParse` method of the `Int` type.

What I usually do is write a separate function to get validated input from the user, then call that from my main code. In this case, since you have upper and lower bound requirements, you might consider writing something like this:

```
public static int GetBoundedIntFromUser(int minVal, int maxVal)
{
    if (minVal >= maxVal)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("minVal must be less than maxVal.");
    }

    int input;

    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter a number from {0} to {1}: ", minVal, maxVal);

        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input)
            && input >= minVal && input <= maxVal)
        {
            break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("That input is not valid. Please try again.");
    }

    return input;
}
```

Then you can just call it from your main code (without any try catch), like:

```
switch (GetBoundedIntFromUser(1, 3))
{
    case 1:
        singleGrade.grapher(acount, bcount, ccount, dcount, ecount, fcount);
        break;

    case 2:
        readIn.Classes(SingleGrade[1]);
        break;

    case 3:
        countAll.allGrades(multiGrade);
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```